# Change Facebook like button design

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I'd like to change the like button design of facebook's default like button on my page, because it just doesn't fit in there and it looks horrible anyways... =)

Approach 1: Use Javascript to change design inside iframe. => Failed because the iframe is on domain "facebook.com" and the script runs on my site...

Approach 2: Simply put an image over the actual button. => Always goes into background, dirty solution anyway...

Approach 3: Look at 9gag.com's like button (they did it nicely). => Couldn't figure out, what exactly they are doing, they're triggering some JS when the button is clicked, but I have no clue what happens then...

Can anyone think of some better solutions, or give me a hint how the 9gaggers did it? Btw, my website is [lolkitten.org](http://lolkitten.org/), feel free to lay your hands on it... =)

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I just found this tutorial earlier today: 
http://olegnax.com/492-custom-share-button-facebook/

Comment: Hmm... This helps to define a custom share button linking to facebook, but doesn't allow to process a like click, i.e. define own like buttons...